# how to Include json manifest file in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, progressive-web-apps

I want to build a pwa from my wordpress site and I don't want to use any plugin to do so how do I add a manifest.json file to my wordpress site please?

Answer (score 2):

Open your function file from your theme directory  and add the following code

```
  //manifest file
add_action( 'wp_head', 'inc_manifest_link' );

// Creates the link tag
function inc_manifest_link() {   
        echo '<link rel="manifest" href="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/manifest.json">';
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is a bad idea. It should be done on the child theme only!
See other options here : https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-javascript-to-your-wordpress-site--cms-34368